# Complex form in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am about to develop a pretty big form in GWT and I have the traditional: "which layout should i start with"?

When I say "complex" form, it is roughly 25 fields, with some lookup, explanations...

I use uibinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT translates Java into JavaScript. Nothing more. When you think about layouts, think HTML and CSS first. You can create a very complex layout using Ui:Binder without a single line of Java code. You will need GWT for handlers and such.

GWT does offer some widgets - like a LayoutPanel - for convenience. So you can use it as a container for your form, possibly split into a couple of layers (left and right column), with each layer containing an HTMLPanel (or ScrollPanel and then an HTMLPanel inside of a ScrollPanel). Then you add all your fields into each of these HTMLPanels.